# Need to extract only part after last hyphen(-) for every record in a column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have records in a column, from which I need to extract the string (no need of numeric values) after last hyphen(-).

I tried with `SPLIT_PART` in Snowflake as the format is not same for all records I get `NULL` for couple of records. When I query need only string after last hyphen(-) symbol.

The data looks something like below.

```
IN-43 West india branch
BRANCH - KA - Bengaluru
REMOTE - AP - Hyderabad
FUSION - collide - AB - Writing
Rock - Allay - KA - Mysore
KA-18 Rock salt
FUSION - myth - KA - Area south
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample data formatted to understand the actual data which needs to be processed?

Comment: Please try to share your data in text, images are worse than even badly formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this one?

```
with mydata as (
select * from values 
  (' IN-43 West india branch' ),
  ('BRANCH- KA - Bengaluru'),
  ('KA-Fusion strength (01)'),
  ('FUSION - myth - KA - Area south') tmp(column_name ))
select regexp_replace( REGEXP_SUBSTR( column_name, '.*-[0-9 ]*(.*)$',1,1,'e' ), '[^a-zA-Z ]*','')  res
from mydata;
    
+-------------------+
|        RES        |
+-------------------+
| West india branch |
| Bengaluru         |
| Fusion strength   |
| Area south        |
+-------------------+
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html

First REGEXP_SUBSTR extract the data based on the end of line ($), the  regexp_replace clears special characters and digits.

Comment: Can we tune it little more to ignore numeric values in the extracted part

Comment: @Abhi sure, I updated my answer ;)

Comment: Its working as per the requirement, but i see we are loosing some records.

Comment: @Abhi Which records? I just added 3 rows to my sample. Could you tell me which record is not parsed? So I can add it to test

Comment: KA-Fusion strength (01)  For this records getting only ')' instead of Fusion strength.

Comment: @Abhi It wasn't in your sample, right? Anyway, I updated my answer. I hope I didn't miss any untold requirements :)

Comment: Thanks much atil, i will try for further things, could you please help me in understanding this       '.*-[0-9 ]*(.*)$',1,1,'e'    I will try for requirements on my own.

Comment: Still the above answer gives (01) in extracted part, can remove numeric and special characters.

Comment: @Abhi could you tell me what is exactly required? I answered 3 times, and all of them were correct but I had to update because of missing requirements.

Comment: Add the sample row, and the output please

Comment: String present after last ifen(-) without any numeric or special characters.  KA-Fusion strength (01) for this need only Fusion strength as output.

Comment: Thanks much, this helps my requirement.

Comment: That's great. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct to help the community!

Answer (score 1):

[SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html) supports NEGATIVE part number:

> **If the value is negative, the parts are counted backward from the end of the string.**

```
SELECT col, SPLIT_PART(col, '-', -1) AS last_part
FROM tab;
```

Removing digits is just a matter of using `TRANSLATE` and replacing them with empty string:

```
TRANSLATE(SPLIT_PART(col, '-', -1), '0123456789', '')
```

---

Full demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col TEXT)
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES
('IN-43 West india branch')
,('BRANCH - KA - Bengaluru')
,('REMOTE - AP - Hyderabad')
,('FUSION - collide - AB - Writing')
,('Rock - Allay - KA - Mysore')
,('KA-18 Rock salt')
,('FUSION - myth - KA - Area south');

SELECT col, TRIM(TRANSLATE(SPLIT_PART(col, '-', -1), '0123456789', '')) AS last_part
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]